# Assign method in Scala

Tags: scala, operator-overloading, variable-assignment, scala-2.8

When this code is executed:

```
var a = 24
var b = Array (1, 2, 3)
a = 42
b = Array (3, 4, 5)
b (1) = 42
```

I see three (five?) assignments here. What is the name of the method call that is called in such circumstances?
Is it operator overloading?

**Update:**
Can I create a class and overload assignment? ( x = y not x(1) = y )

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Having this file:

```
//assignmethod.scala
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    var a = 24
    var b = Array (1, 2, 3)
    a = 42
    b = Array (3, 4, 5)
    b (1) = 42
  }
}
```

running `scalac -print assignmethod.scala` gives us:

```
[[syntax trees at end of cleanup]]// Scala source: assignmethod.scala
package <empty> {
  final class Main extends java.lang.Object with ScalaObject {
    def main(args: Array[java.lang.String]): Unit = {
      var a: Int = 24;
      var b: Array[Int] = scala.Array.apply(1, scala.this.Predef.wrapIntArray(Array[Int]{2, 3}));
      a = 42;
      b = scala.Array.apply(3, scala.this.Predef.wrapIntArray(Array[Int]{4, 5}));
      b.update(1, 42)
    };
    def this(): object Main = {
      Main.super.this();
      ()
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see the compiler just changes the last one (`b (1) = 42`) to the method call:

```
b.update(1, 42)
```

Answer (score 10):

Complementing [Michael's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/189058/michael-kebe) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809984/assign-method-in-scala/2810127#2810127), assignment can't be overridden in Scala, though you can create an assignment-like operator, like `:=`, for example.

The "assignments" that can be overridden are:

```
// method update
a(x) = y 
// method x_=, assuming method x exists and is also visible 
a.x = y
// method +=, though it will be converted to x = x + y if method += doesn't exist
a += y
```

Comment: @Amitabh This is not an assignment, but a declaration, and there's nothing being overridden there. What is the question? That `1` is not a `BigInt`? If that's the case, there's an implicit conversion available from `Int` to `BigInt`, so that the number is converted into an `BigInt` before getting assigned.

Comment: Yes thats the question. I want to make a variant of BigInt (lets call it BI). I am unable to figure out how to do this implicit conversion.

Comment: @Amitabh Then ask a question about it. :) It can be as simple as `object BI { implicit def toBI(n: Int): BI = new BI(n) }`, but explanations and details are not appropriate for a comment thread.